# Should I use loops?

Tags: loops, recursion, functional-programming, tail-recursion, ml

I have been learning the functional programming in ML for quit a while I got 
fixated on the of recursion and tail recursion. 
almost ( rather every ) loop I write in other language I write tail recursive function. 
should I keep doing that or would it confuse probably my future peers or what every?

Answer (score 3):

[Tail recursive calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) are the right way to code "loops" in ML (or Ocaml) language (or Scheme, or even most Common Lisp, but sadly not in [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) which has iterative constructs)

Look e.g. inside the source code of their standard libraries as an example (eg Ocaml's [stdlib](http://caml.inria.fr/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/ocaml/trunk/stdlib/)).

Tail rec calls won't confuse your peers, they are familiar with that.

BTW you could also feel that ordinary loops in procedural languages (e.g. C or Java or C++) are badly hidden tail recursive calls. It is a matter of opinion.

BTW, in Ocaml, I generally name `fooloop` (replace `foo` by a meaningful name, e.g. `findloop` or `scanloop` ...) an internal tail recursive function...

Certainly in Ocaml using a tail-recursive internal function is more idiomatic that e.g. using the `while` construct ...

Another way of looking at tail recursive calls is that they really are "gotos with arguments" (and often implemented as machine jump instructions with a few values passed in machine registers).

Comment: I just want my code to be clean and elegant as possible . 
tail recursion in some situation in not of all situations but some !! 
make sense to me would it confuse you or other programmers ?

Comment: No, that is common practice. However, functions which contain both tail recursive calls and non-tail (i.e. genuinely) recursive calls -to the same function- are in practice not very common.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch If you are searching a binary tree for a value eg. in Scheme you do `(or (recur (car x)) (recur (cdr x)))` in the helper `recur`. The first recursive calls grows the stack while the second is in tail position and do not.

Comment: I know that, but I just said that these are in practice not very common